# SSIS Data Flow Task Running Fine Separately But Not Running When Package is Run

Tags: ssis, hana, sap-bw

My SSIS package has a Data flow task that is running fine and loads data from SAP BW source to SQL Server destination when only that task is run, but it is doing nothing when the package is run. The task, is not failing in the latter case. The source of the DFT is the 'Xtract DeltaQ' source which is a third party source connector provided by Theobald Software. It loads data from SAP BW system. When the package is run, the task is succeeding but is not loading any records to the destination. When the package is run, all the other tasks except this DFT are working fine.

The DFT should load data from SAP BW to SQL Server as expected when we run the package.